Find smallest string after a single substring rotation
I wrote a solution for this code challenge:

Given a string of lower case English letters of length n, select a substring in it and rotate that by 1 position and do this only once such that the result is alphabetically  smallest.
For doing right shift operation, just move characters to right and pick the last character to first position of substring. see below example
Example
Input: "aahhab"
Output: "aaahhb"
Explanation:
Selected substring is [2,4] = "hha". It changes to "ahh"
So the result is the left portion + the substring + the right portion, which is "aa" + "ahh" + "b" = "aaahhb"
Constraints

1 <= n <= 105
The input has only lower case English letters


My code
     public static String solve(String input) {
        int n = input.length();
        String result = input;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                // Extract substring and rotate it
                String substring = input.substring(i, j);
                String rotated = rotateRight(substring);
                
                // Form new message
                String newMessage = input.substring(0, i) + rotated + input.substring(j);
                
                // Update result if new message is lexicographically smaller
                if (newMessage.compareTo(result) < 0) {
                    result = newMessage;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    private static String rotateRight(String s) {
        if (s.length() <= 1) {
            return s;
        }
        return s.charAt(s.length() - 1) + s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
    }

My code runs in O(n^3) because of nested loops and the substring method. The problem is that this is too slow for longer inputs: for a string of size 10000, it already takes a minute to complete. I need it to complete within a fraction of a second.
How to solve this in less than O(n^2) time complexity?

If your code works, but you want to improve it, the question is a candidate for Code Review.

You can find the substring (that needs rotation) in linear time.

To find the ending index (inclusive) of the substring, proceed as follows.
Among all letters that follow after a greater letter (like the "b" in "cb"), find the least letter and the index where it occurs. If there are ties, take the latest occurrence. This index will be the index of the last letter in the substring.

To find the starting index of the substring, proceed as follows.
Find the first letter that is greater than the letter found in the previous step. We know that the letter that precedes it immediately is a candidate, so we are sure to find one somewhere before the index we got from the first step. The substring will start at this index.


Here is an implementation:
    public static String solve(String input) {
        int n = input.length();
        String result = input;

        int j = 0; // The last index of the substring (inclusive!)
        char least = 'z';
        char curr = input.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            char prev = curr;
            curr = input.charAt(i);
            if (curr < prev && curr <= least) {
                j = i;
                least = curr;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) > least) {
                String substring = input.substring(i, j + 1);
                String rotated = rotateRight(substring);
                return input.substring(0, i) + rotated + input.substring(j + 1);
            }
        }
        return input; // The input is sorted; no rotation can improve that.
    }

Note that this function returns the resulting string. Up to you to print it.
Proof
Let's name the two anchor indices for the substring to be rotated  and , so that the letter [] will be moved to index , and all other letters in between will shift to the right. Let's call the pair (, ) the "solution" when the corresponding rotation leads to the lexically smallest result string.
We can take the following constructive steps for creating a list of candidates for (, ) and then reducing that list to just one such pair:
1. [] > []
First, we can observe that if [] < [], then the rotation creates a result string that is lexically greater than the input string, and thus is not a solution. If [] > [], then we get a lexically smaller input string, which is a candidate. Remains the case where [] == []. Then we have a few cases to consider:

For all  with  <  < , we have [] = []. In this case the rotation does not change the input string; we can discard this option.

Let  be the smallest index with  <  for which [] != []. Then we have these two sub-cases:

[] < []. In this case the rotation will result in a greater string: it is not a solution.

[] > []. In this case the rotation will result in a smaller string. But then we could also have chosen  equal to this , which gives the same result, so that we arrive in the case where [] > [].




So we can discard the cases where [] = [], and require that [] > []. If there is no such index pair, then the input string is the solution. No rotation can improve on that.
2. Minimise 
We can see that among all index pairs (, ) that fit the previous condition, we should go for those that minimise : as the first letter in the result that is "reduced" (compared to the original string) is the one at index , the ones that reduce a letter at a smaller index give a better (lexically smaller) result.
3. [-1] > []
If [-1] = [], then we might as well select −1 as the last index for the rotation: the result of the rotation will be the same, so we can discard this case for the solution.
If [−1] < [], then if we select −1 as last index of the rotated substring, we will get a lexically smaller output string. So we should exclude this  for the solution.
4. Select  for which [] is minimised
Of all valid index pairs (, ) that satisfy the above requirements (note that they all have the same ), get the minimum letter [] among []. Then reject any index pair (, ) for which [] is not that minimum letter. This is because that [] will be moved to index  by the rotation, so the better result is achieved with the smallest letter.
5. Maximise 
Let's say we have two index pairs that satisfy all of the above constraints, (, 1) and (, 2), with 1 < 2. We can visualise the input string as follows (with some example letters filled in):
"....f...pe...qe...."
     ↑    ↑    ↑
         1    2

When the rotation on (, 1) is performed, we get 1:
"....ef...p...qe...."
     ↑    ↑    ↑
         1    2

If on the other hand, the rotation on (, 2) is performed, we get 2:
"....ef...pe...q...."
     ↑    ↑    ↑
         1    2

Now note how the two result strings only differ by one rotation on the interval (1+1, 2). If we apply that rotation on 1, we get 2: that rotation re-inserts the common letter (that was originally at both indices 1 and 2, and which is "e" in the example) at index 1+1, just "as if" it was shifted right from its source position at index 1, and "as if" the one that was originally at index 2 was re-inserted at index .
What can we say about the effect on 1 when we apply a rotation on (1+1, 2)?
Let  be the first index after 1 that has a letter greater than the (common) letter at 2. We know  will be less than 2 because 2−1 is a candidate. Then all letters between indices 1 and −1 (inclusive) are the same (cf. rule #4 above). From this follows that 2 is lexically smaller than 1.
The conclusion is that we should maximise . This gives us one unique (, ) pair for which the corresponding rotation necessarily gives the lexically minimal result string.
The algorithm follows from the above five reductions of the candidate set.

This could use a proof.  Specifically, it's tough to see that the choice of the latest least letter in step 1 is optimal.

@Matt, I added a proof -- a bit too verbose to my liking, but I think it works.

vey nicely structured

I have a vague feeling this appeared as a contest problem in recent months, but can't find it. If anyone finds a link, that'd be good for testing and should have an official solution explanation. For now, I'm just going to give my solution with proof.
Let's forget rotation, the problem's asking us to move one character to the left (or leave the string unchanged, corresponding to rotating a substring with only that character). In other words, remove a character and reinsert it.
Count the occurrences of every character and use them to sort the characters in the input string, then compare the input string with this sorted string S. For the first i position where they differ, we know that there's at least one occurrence of character S[i] in input[i+1:] (Python substring notation), so we can construct a solution which has S[:i+1] as a prefix. (If they don't differ, the input is already smallest.) At the same time, there's no solution with a smaller prefix than S, so this is optimal and we must move some occurrence of S[i] from input[i+1:] to position i in order to create the optimal solution.
For simplicity, let's assume that if there are multiple consecutive occurrences of S[i] in input[i+1:] (e.g. "aaaa"), we're moving the last one, since the resulting string is the same no matter which we move.
We've already inserted an occurrence of S[i] into the input, creating a temp string. We also need to remove an occurrence of S[i] from temp such that the resulting string is lexicographically smallest. If we remove an occurrence at position j which isn't the end of temp, then the character at position j in the final solution will be strictly greater than S[i]; otherwise, it'll be exactly S[i]. To create the lexicograpically smallest solution, it's better to increase a character at a larger index than a smaller one, and even better if we can remove S[i] from the end of temp, so the optimal solution is removing the last occurrence of S[i] from temp. Note that this position of remove is indeed after the position of insert.
These are 2 linear-time decisions.

"we're moving the last one, since the resulting string is the same no matter which we move.": no, the resulting string is not necessarily the same.

@trincot Wrong, e.g. "baaab" moving 1st, 2nd or 3rd "a" to the front gives "abaab" everytime. Maybe you missed that I'm talking about consecutive occurrences there.

You spoke of multiple consecutive occurrences, which I take to mean something like "baaabaaabaaabaaab". Maybe clarify this.

@trincot That's not what consecutive is, but sure, I'll extra clarify.

"consecutive occurrences" is clear. When you have multiple of them, it becomes problematic.

@trincot I meant that as consecutive kind of multiple occurrences, not as multiple of "consecutive occurrences".


Find first non "a" character. Let's call it x
Find smallest character less then one from point 1. Call it y
Rotate string that start from character x and ends with y

If 2. fail try with "b"  then "c" and so on.
PS: It fails in some corner case.
Point 2. need to to be fixed to chose proper position if there are several options.
